# 1С 8.3 (Обычный). Как добавить список значений в отбор (ВидСравнения.ВСписке)

Tags: 1с

Код:

```
МассивРабот = Новый Массив();
МассивРабот.Добавить("Товар1");
МассивРабот.Добавить("Товар2");                                    

СписокТоваров = Новый СписокЗначений;
СписокТоваров.ЗагрузитьЗначения(МассивАвторабот);                      

СправочникСписок.Отбор.Наименование.Установить(СписокТоваров);
СправочникСписок.Отбор.Наименование.ВидСравнения = ВидСравнения.ВСписке;  
СправочникСписок.Отбор.Наименование.Использование = Истина;
```

Получается такой результат добавления в отбор:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А должно быть так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Может так?

```
СписокТоваров = Новый СписокЗначений;                
СписокТоваров.Добавить("Товар1");
СписокТоваров.Добавить("Товар2");  

СправочникСписок.Отбор.Наименование.Значение = СписокТоваров;
СправочникСписок.Отбор.Наименование.ВидСравнения = ВидСравнения.ВСписке;  
СправочникСписок.Отбор.Наименование.Использование = Истина;
```